# Can I install R from within RStudio?

Tags: r, rstudio

R version 3 is released as announced at R bloggers. I am using RStudio and would like to know if it is possible to install the new version from within RStudio. Any precautions for may installed packages, functions and data?

Answer (score 3):

RStudio has built-in support for updating packages, but not for updating R itself.

If you're using Windows, the `installr` package can be used to update R (as was mentioned on [R-bloggers](http://www.r-bloggers.com/r-3-0-0-is-released-whats-new-and-how-to-upgrade/)). Otherwise your update will need to be more manual.